# Combining VLOOKUP and IFERROR in formula

Tags: excel, vba

First time poster here, long time reader. I've seen a few threads describing similar issues to this, but haven't really understood the answer and wanted to see if my situation is the same. I work at a company where I have taken over some of the duties of a previous "coder." He was school-trained but appears to have mostly recorded code with the macro recording tool. He's been gone a couple of years and some of his work has started to break. I've been assigned with no formal training to fix his work and make it more resilient for the future. I don't have any formal training. I'm hoping that you can teach me when I get over my head and when my google-fu fails me.

I've run into one of those situations now. I've got a piece of code that runs a vlookup . Its basically taking the previous coder's R1C1 vlookup and looking across a sheet to pull another column from another sheet.  I want to throw an IFERROR() around the whole thing and tag another vlookup on the other side, but nothing I've tried thus far has worked. Is it possible without a lot of code? Any help or guidance is welcome. Here's the code:

```
    Range("AG2").Select 
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(datevalue(RC[-21])&RC[-20],'Rate Vlookup'!R2C3:R" & lastrow & "C36,4,FALSE)"
    Range("AG2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AG2:AG" & lrow), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Edit- 2020-06-04:
Here's one thing that I've tried. I've been looking at this over the last two weeks and skipping around so I haven't always kept my work, so there are definitely others that I didn't write down/keep. Is that a best practice that I'm missing?

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=iferror((VLOOKUP(datevalue(RC[-21])&RC[-20],'Rate Vlookup'!R2C3:R" & lastrow & "C36,4,FALSE),VLOOKUP(datevalue(RC[-21])&RC[-20],'Rate Vlookup'!R2C3:R" & lastrow & "C36,4,FALSE))" 'This returned a run-time 1004 error when I tried it on that very line of code.
```

Made some progress, with the following code but like someone said what do I do when the vlookup still doesn't work. Its still a scenario like that.

Here's the working code:

```
 ActiveCell.Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(L2&M2,'Rate Vlookup'!C2:AL" & lastrow & ",4, FALSE),VLOOKUP(DATEVALUE(L2&M2),'Rate Vlookup'!C2:AL" & lastrow & ",4, FALSE))"
```

Like I said, its still bleeding errors and now I have to consider that, but I think this question is answered. Thank you all.

Comment: Welcome to SO (for posting questions at least!). What have you tried so far? Please update your question with your code samples you have tried (even if they don't work) and include some data samples to show us what you currently have and what your desired outcome is.

Comment: I would avoid R1C1 formulas here...

Comment: Iferror(vlookup1,vlookup2) but what happens if vlookup2 fails.

Comment: @urdearboy Thank you and I definitely agree and don't enjoy the R1C1 formulas. They remind me that underlying everything is recorded code and that feels sluggish to me, and it doesn't feel "mine."  I have another workbook where I eliminated all of them and made direct references to the cells that I wanted to touch. Unfortunately this broke other code and I have a very short deadline on this project(which I've missed and am trying desperately to complete asap. I will be going back and gutting this though and making it "my own"

Comment: @SamuelEverson Thank you for the kind welcome! I added the only example that I can find. I did find some other examples on google that I was going to try, but I wanted to reach out here first to see what others said before regutting the program again and putting myself further off. I'm not sure that I can show the data samples, because its proprietary to the company. I want to share but not at the expense of the job. Its hard to walk that line. I'm sorry!

Comment: @SolarMike I thought that might be how it goes, and I added an example to the regular post of how I attempted that, but I must have the syntax wrong because it keeps causing run-time 1004 errors when I run it. I understand what you mean about vlookup2 failing. Do you have any suggestions? I'm pretty sure that I've captured the two main scenarios that would trigger the vlookups. Is there a way to capture other errors?  I'm so new to this. Its embarrassing. I want to build something that lasts, not that breaks ten minutes after delivery.

Comment: No worries, having a look at your edit now - for future, to make a [mcve], use dummy data - I tend to just type the cell address into each cell (i.e `A1` goes in cell `A1` etc.) that way you can demonstrate at least what the problem is without risk of publishing something you shouldn't. - the other benefit of seeing some sample data is there might be a "better" way to do what you're trying to do. (I say "better" as i feel it's a subjective term).